# Setting priority between MUI System Props and Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

When using Styled Components with MUI System Props I found that the styled component styling takes precedence, for example in the snippet below the box would render with `justify content` set as `space-around`:

```
const CustomBox = styled(Box)(() => ({
  display: 'flex',
  justifiyContent: 'center'
}));

function MyComponent() (
  <CustomBox justifyContent='space-around'>
    <span className='some-icon'></span>
    <span>some text</span>
  </CustomBox>
)
```

I could manage this "the styled components way" and pass a prop to `CustomBox`, but I find it counter-intuitive that the MIUI system prop looks like a local override, but is overriden by the component it's being applied to.

**Is there some configuration available in MUI that would make MUI System Props take precedence over Styled Components stylings?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the props passed to the `CustomBox` to win over your style overrides, then you should take the props into account in your styling:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
const CustomBox = styled(Box)(({ display, justifyContent }) => ({
  display: display === undefined ? "flex" : display,
  justifyContent: justifyContent === undefined ? "center" : justifyContent
}));
export default function BoxSx() {
  return (
    <>
      <CustomBox>
        <span>Span 1 - no changes</span>
        <span>Span 2 - no changes</span>
      </CustomBox>
      <CustomBox justifyContent="space-around">
        <span>Span 1 - justifyContent="space-around"</span>
        <span>Span 2 = justifyContent="space-around"</span>
      </CustomBox>
      <CustomBox
        justifyContent="space-around"
        sx={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}
      >
        <span>Span 1 - sx justifyContent="space-between"</span>
        <span>Span 2 = sx justifyContent="space-between"</span>
      </CustomBox>
      <CustomBox display="none">
        <span>Span 1 - display="none"</span>
        <span>Span 2 - display="none"</span>
      </CustomBox>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit CustomBox]

As far as why the props don't automatically take precedence -- the props change the default styling for the `Box` and that default styling is what the `styled` API is then overriding. Since the `styled` API gives you access to those props, it allows you to decide how those props interact with your styling.

In contrast, the `sx` prop provides styles that are applied with a different precedence than the default styles, so providing `justifyContent` within `sx` wins over both the props and styles provided via `styled`.

Comment: in the end I went with something like `justifyContent: justifyContent || 'center'`, but I might switch to the sx prop (I didn't know it had different priority than system props...)

Answer (score 1):

The styles attached with [`styled`](https://mui.com/system/styled/) is overridden by the [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/) on the component. Usually this can be used to add any additional local styles to a `styled` component with MUI.

Unless specified to disable it, `styled` also add support for the `sx` prop by default if used with a base JSX component such as`div`, for quick style overrides.

More examples on a demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-phht84?file=src/App.js)

```
const CustomBox = styled(Box)({
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
});
```

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <CustomBox sx={{ justifyContent: "flex-start" }}>
      <span className="some-icon"></span>
      <span>some text</span>
    </CustomBox>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'll have to figure out if my team will prefer using the sx prop or explicit prop passing as in @Ryan Cogswell's answer... but this is a good answer